# How do we pick objects from a model to create copies in another model adding extra parameters in django?

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    questionnaire_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")
    ...

class Question(models.Model):
    question_body = models.TextField()
    ...

class QuestionnaireContent(models.Model):
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    ...
```

The `QuestionnaireContent` model acts as a list of questionnaire templates. Those are assigned to users eventually, using:

```
class QuestionnaireAssignment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire)
```

Now, ideally, I would like this assignment to generate a new questionnaire 'instance' in another model which would have the following fields:

```
class QuestionnaireInstance(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    visibility = models.BooleanField()
```

But I would like that `QuestionnaireInstance` to be created automatically once a `QuestionnaireAssignment` instance is created. I guess I could rewrite the save function of `QuestionnaireAssignment`but I am wondering if there is a simpler/cleaner way to do this?

The idea is I want from the template questionnaires to create instance for users that can be customized for that user (adding attribute visibility and eventually changing the questions).

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Overriding the `save()` method of `QuetionnaireAssignment` is one possibility. You could also look at using the `postsave` signal instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/

Comment: Question: Why do you have `QuestionnaireInstance`, `QuestionnaireAssignment`, and `QuestionnaireContent`? These all look very similar. What is the difference between these? I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that QuestionnaireContent is supposed to be a template from which to pick, these are built by picking in a list of questions. You might want to have different templates assigned to different customers, which is where I do QuestionnaireAssignment. And once assigned, you might want to edit that template, and keep track of the modifications, that's why I have the QuestionnaireInstance. Maybe I could merge QuestionnaireAssignment and QuestionnaireContent indeed to make things simple, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: But the question remains with two models.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: yes indeed, I think that is what I will have to do. Thanks for the link to ```postsave``` documentation, that is new to me

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the `save()` method of `QuetionnaireAssignment` is one possibility. Note that you don't have to completely rewrite `save()` since you can call `super().save()`.

Alternatively, use the `postsave` signal instead: docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals